# Need to create wider container in Bootstrap - 1920px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I have .psd design for client site, graphic designer drew container width up to 1920px, and I need a help how to properly set up width of container to 1920px.

I know how to set up smaller

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
      width: 1170px;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Instead of forcing your containers to 1920px and overriding the default bootstrap grid sizes, you may want to look at `.container-fluid`, which is inside Bootstrap's packaged css.

**Containers**

Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    ...
</div>
```

***Link***: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Answer (score 6):

You could utilize Bootstrap's **container-fluid** class to fill the entire width first, then you can restrict the width responsively... Here is an example in Sass:

```
.wide-container {
    @extend .container-fluid; // which has max-width: auto; (full)
}

// on medium screens and beyond...
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    .wide-container {
        max-width: 1470px; // limit the width here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just reuse the media query you have above, and simply decide when you want the container to change to that size (something greater than 1920px).

```
   @media (min-width: YOUR VALUE HERE)
    .container {
          width: 1920px;
    }
```

OR, upon reading your question again, you said, "up to 1920px", so a fluid container?
Then simply set:

```
.container {
      max-width: 1920px;
      width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I want in every moment width of container to be 1920px, not up to, sorry my fault. My monitor is 1200px resolution, but I must use 1920px

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not clear enough. but if you want to set up 1920px wide container, just override the default container width with "!important". like this,

```
.container { width: 1920px !important; }
```

Or if you wish to 1920px container only for larger displays, you can use media query like this,

```
@media (min-width: 2400px) {
  .container {
      width: 1920px; 
  }
}
```

this rule will apply only for displays that is at least 2400px wide.

Comment: I want in every moment width of container to be 1920px, not up to, sorry my fault. My monitor is 1200px resolution, but I must use 1920px

Comment: then you just need to set: .container{ width: 1920px}

Comment: thanks, that's it... but now I have another question, how will it affect the responsive design, when I resize the browser window?

Comment: @MileMijatović responsive means you are setting different settings for different width sizes. So if you use  .container { width: 1920px !important; }, then thats the resolution for all browser widths. If you want to preserve responsiveness, you have to define media queries for different browser sizes

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your own CSS according to the screen size you want to show as the below example will work on a larger resolution size than 1599px.

```
@media (min-width: 1600px)
.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override BootStrap's default styling as the answers above describe, or you could create a new class such as:

```
.container.wide {
   width: 1920px;
}
```

Then add the class to the container `<div>`'s such as:

```
<div class="container wide">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

This ensures only the `<div>`'s you add the `wide` class to are effected, meaning you're still free to use `<div class="container">` for normal BootStrap container behavior if required.

**EDIT**

As Vikas has said in his comment, the above style would apply also on mobile. In this case, just wrap in a media query as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 1950px) { 
    .container.wide { width: 1920px; } 
}
```

Comment: this will always set container to 1920px even in mobile

Comment: @VikasKandari True but you could just wrap in a media query instead - updated answer accordingly.

Comment: wide class doesnt require just put media query rule at the bottom other other rules or just put css stylesheet after bootstrap css this will overwrite container properties when width exceeds min-width in media query rule

Comment: @VikasKandari I prefer adding my own classes so I don't directly override Bootstrap's classes. This makes it easier to revert back to core Bootstrap if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This css will override bootstrap's container sizing.  Adjust the max-width values as needed. Tested with bootstrap 4.6.1

```css
/* Override bootstrap to make containers wider by 60px */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    .container, .container-sm {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container, .container-md, .container-sm {
        max-width: 780px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
        max-width: 1020px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Based on your reactions you probably want

```
.container{
    width: 1920px !important;
}
```

though I don't understand why :). On every smaller resolution it will scroll now.

Comment: Down voted - this will always set container to 1920px even in mobile